# Get label value of a virtual node neo4j apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

How to retrieve a label value of a virtual node created by apoc proc?
The following returns the id of a node and null for the label value

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (cd:Day) WHERE cd.yyyymmdd= 20190609 
call  apoc.create.vNode(['Day'],{yyyymmdd:20190609})  yield node as vd
WITH Coalesce(cd, vd) as td  
return ID(td) as id, td.yyyymmdd as f
```

Comment: You are not returning label field then how are you getting `null` for Label?

Comment: Do you mean `null` for property value (`yyyymmdd`)?

Comment: that is correct, yyyymmdd is returned with null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Virtual nodes/relationships are mainly used for visualization.**

**Cypher itself can't access them.** 
There are a bunch of functions in `apoc` to access their properties, labels, and rel-types.

You can use [`apoc.any.property`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#node-functions) to access a property for virtual and real, nodes, relationships.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (cd:Day) WHERE cd.yyyymmdd= 20190609 
CALL  apoc.create.vNode(['Day'],{yyyymmdd:20190609})  YIELD node AS vd
WITH Coalesce(cd, vd) AS td  
RETURN ID(td) AS id, apoc.any.property(td, 'yyyymmdd') AS f
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.